# Residue theorem on even function integration

Tags: integration, contour-integration

I need to integrate below function;
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(pR)}{R}\frac{p}{k^2-p^2} dp$$
here $k,R$ are constants.
Since this is an even function of $p$, I tried applying the residue theorem.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ipR}-e^{-ipR}}{2iR}\frac{p}{k^2-p^2} dp$$
Now taking $z=pR, dz=R dp$;
$$\int \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2iR}\frac{z}{k^2R^2-z^2} dz$$

$$\frac{\pi i}{2i}\frac{1}{R}[{(\lim{z \rightarrow kR})} \ \frac{(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})z}{k^2R^2-z^2}(z-kR) +{(\lim{z \rightarrow -kR})} \frac{(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})z}{k^2R^2-z^2}(z+kR)]$$
This gives me zero as the answer. However, since this is an even function integration cannot be zero.
Any small help on this highly appreciated.

Comment: what contour are you using, and, which simple pole is found within it?

Comment: @James S. Cook poles are $p=k,-k$. I used half circle. Correct me if I am wrong. I am doing a mistake here, but I still could not figure it out. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the notation in the last equation.

Comment: @joriki I modified the last equation. Hope now it is clear:)

Comment: Only one of the exponentials is small on a semicircle in either half-plane. If $R$ and $k$ are real, use $\frac{\sin (pR)}{R} = \operatorname{Im} \frac{\exp (ip\lvert R\rvert)}{\lvert R\rvert}$ and a semicircle in the upper half-plane. Otherwise, split the integrand and use the upper half-plane for one part and the lower half-plane for the other, each with the exponential that is small on the respective semicircle.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I think that's an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @joriki Only if I don't find a duplicate.

Comment: @user50724: Are you aware you can write proper limits like this? `\lim_{z\to kR}`

Comment: Some questions where the problem of using the upper resp. lower half-plane for each of the exponential terms is touched: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/861230/the-integral-int-0-infty-dfracx-sinxx21-dx), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843675/use-contour-integration-methods-to-compute-int-mathbbr-frac-cos-x1-x2), [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/343823/contour-integration-of-sinx-xx3). Not sure whether any of those qualifies as a duplicate candidate.

Comment: @DanielFischer many thanks for the explanation  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $R$ is a positive real number,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\color{red}{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{z\sin(R z)}{k^2-z^2}\,dz &=&\frac{1}{2}\,\color{red}{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(Rz)}{k-z}-\frac{\sin(Rz)}{k+z}\right)\,dz\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\,\color{red}{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\sin z}{R k-z}-\frac{\sin z}{R k+z}\right)\,dz\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\,\text{Im}\left(-2\pi i\,e^{ikR} \right)\\&=&-\pi\,\text{Re}\left(e^{ikR}\right)\\&=&\color{red}{-\pi\cos(R\cdot \text{Re}\, k)\exp(-R\cdot\text{Im}\, k)}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Thanks for this Principal value approach. Would you mind giving a small explanation on arriving from step 2 to step 3? Thanks

Comment: @user50724: we just have to compute $$PV\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\,dz,$$ translate the variable $z$, then take the imaginary part.